# Network with vlans, tcpdump show connections and icmp replies and requests, but ping not received

Tags: networking, dhcp

I have network with switches which have set pvid on every port on every switch to 1.
Server is on linux debian with authoritative dhcp. 
Some of ip addresses do not have access to gateway. I dont know what is blocking: switches or gateway.

The most strange thing is that on ping request, gateway receive it and answer on it. Client also send request and receive answer, but ping program does not show replies. I checked replies with tcpdump:

Client tcpdump:

```
18:18:20.283614 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.0.102 tell 192.168.1.1, length 46
18:18:21.135348 IP kicok-K53SJ > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 46, length 64
18:18:43.766916 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.0.101 tell 192.168.1.1, length 46
18:18:44.135326 IP kicok-K53SJ > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 69, length 64
18:18:44.164008 IP 192.168.1.1 > kicok-K53SJ: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 69, length 64
18:18:44.238354 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.1 tell 192.168.0.234, length 46
18:18:44.618056 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.0.102 tell 192.168.1.1, length 46
18:19:09.135332 IP kicok-K53SJ > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 94, length 64
18:19:09.139740 IP 192.168.1.1 > kicok-K53SJ: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 94, length 64
18:19:09.332947 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.0.102 tell 192.168.1.1, length 46
18:19:10.135329 IP kicok-K53SJ > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 95, length 64
18:19:10.137030 IP 192.168.1.1 > kicok-K53SJ: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 95, length 64
18:19:11.135345 IP kicok-K53SJ > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 96, length 64
18:19:33.771534 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.0.101 tell 192.168.1.1, length 46
18:19:34.121969 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.1 tell 192.168.0.55, length 46
18:19:34.135323 IP kicok-K53SJ > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 119, length 64
18:19:34.139833 IP 192.168.1.1 > kicok-K53SJ: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 119, length 64
18:19:34.218611 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.0.102 tell 192.168.1.1, length 46
18:19:34.771301 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.0.101 tell 192.168.1.1, length 46
18:19:35.135326 IP kicok-K53SJ > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 120, length 64
18:19:58.969345 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.0.102 tell 192.168.1.1, length 46
18:19:59.135327 IP kicok-K53SJ > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 144, length 64
18:19:59.143169 IP 192.168.1.1 > kicok-K53SJ: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 144, length 64


18:18:36.955859 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 60, length 64
18:18:37.950910 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 61, length 64
18:18:37.955877 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 61, length 64
18:18:38.950981 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 62, length 64
18:18:38.956643 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 62, length 64
18:18:39.951068 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 63, length 64
18:18:39.956960 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 63, length 64
18:18:40.583070 IP 192.168.1.133.mdns > 224.0.0.251.mdns: 0 PTR (QM)? 101.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (44)
18:18:40.951113 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 64, length 64
18:18:40.969777 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 64, length 64
18:18:41.584863 IP 192.168.1.133.mdns > 224.0.0.251.mdns: 0 PTR (QM)? 101.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (44)
18:18:41.951164 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 65, length 64
18:18:41.965874 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 65, length 64
18:18:42.951232 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 66, length 64
18:18:42.957989 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 66, length 64
18:18:43.587702 IP 192.168.1.133.mdns > 224.0.0.251.mdns: 0 PTR (QM)? 101.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (44)
18:18:43.951288 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 67, length 64
18:18:43.978219 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 67, length 64
18:18:44.951377 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 68, length 64
18:18:44.980280 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 68, length 64
18:18:45.485589 IP 192.168.1.133.60758 > xxx.pl.domain: 57978+ PTR? 210.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (44)
18:18:45.490642 IP xxx.pl.domain > 192.168.1.133.60758: 57978 NXDomain 0/1/0 (115)
18:18:45.951413 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 69, length 64
18:18:45.979881 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 69, length 64
18:18:46.951478 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 70, length 64
18:18:46.972661 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 70, length 64
18:18:47.951557 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 71, length 64
18:18:47.982161 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 71, length 64
18:18:48.951626 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 72, length 64
18:18:48.977249 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 72, length 64
18:18:49.951717 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 73, length 64
18:18:49.953255 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 73, length 64
18:18:50.491068 IP 192.168.1.133.43288 > dns.xxx.pl.domain: 57978+ PTR? 210.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (44)
18:18:50.566751 IP dns.xxx.pl.domain > 192.168.1.133.43288: 57978 NXDomain 0/1/0 (115)
18:18:50.951760 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 74, length 64
18:18:50.953278 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 74, length 64
18:18:51.951802 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 75, length 64
18:18:51.960164 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 75, length 64
18:18:52.951854 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 76, length 64
18:18:52.953091 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 76, length 64
18:18:53.951879 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 77, length 64
18:18:53.953604 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 77, length 64
18:18:54.951972 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 78, length 64
18:18:54.954378 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 78, length 64
18:18:55.496499 IP 192.168.1.133.60758 > xxx.xxx.pl.domain: 57978+ PTR? 210.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (44)
18:18:55.501014 IP xxx.pl.domain > 192.168.1.133.60758: 57978 NXDomain 0/1/0 (115)
18:18:55.951978 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 79, length 64
18:18:55.956163 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 79, length 64
18:18:56.952149 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 80, length 64
18:18:56.960399 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 80, length 64
18:18:57.952172 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 81, length 64
18:18:57.952201 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 81, length 64
18:18:58.952182 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 82, length 64
18:18:58.952203 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 82, length 64
18:18:59.952278 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 83, length 64
18:18:59.958884 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 83, length 64
18:19:00.501918 IP 192.168.1.133.43288 > xxx.pl.domain: 57978+ PTR? 210.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (44)
18:19:00.507208 IP dns.xxx.pl.domain > 192.168.1.133.43288: 57978 NXDomain 0/1/0 (115)
18:19:00.952422 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 84, length 64
18:19:00.955510 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 84, length 64
18:19:01.952401 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 85, length 64
18:19:01.952870 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 85, length 64
18:19:02.952495 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 86, length 64
18:19:02.953525 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 86, length 64
18:19:03.952538 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 87, length 64
18:19:03.952904 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 87, length 64
18:19:04.952573 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 88, length 64
18:19:04.953364 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 88, length 64
18:19:05.608089 IP 192.168.1.133.mdns > 224.0.0.251.mdns: 0 PTR (QM)? 210.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (44)
18:19:05.952649 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 89, length 64
18:19:05.952904 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 89, length 64
18:19:06.609875 IP 192.168.1.133.mdns > 224.0.0.251.mdns: 0 PTR (QM)? 210.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (44)
18:19:06.952744 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 90, length 64
18:19:06.953540 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 90, length 64
18:19:07.952727 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 91, length 64
18:19:07.953864 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 91, length 64
18:19:08.612728 IP 192.168.1.133.mdns > 224.0.0.251.mdns: 0 PTR (QM)? 210.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (44)
18:19:08.952852 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 92, length 64
18:19:08.954535 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 92, length 64
18:19:09.952912 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 93, length 64
18:19:09.953297 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 93, length 64
18:19:10.510580 IP 192.168.1.133.35953 > xxx.pl.domain: 64751+ PTR? 155.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (44)
18:19:10.518416 IP xxx.pl.domain > 192.168.1.133.35953: 64751 NXDomain 0/1/0 (115)
18:19:10.952931 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 94, length 64
18:19:10.957117 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 94, length 64
18:19:11.953017 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 95, length 64
18:19:11.954464 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 95, length 64
18:19:12.953078 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 96, length 64
18:19:12.957269 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 96, length 64
18:19:13.953118 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 97, length 64
18:19:13.956323 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 97, length 64
18:19:14.953260 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 98, length 64
18:19:14.954302 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 98, length 64
18:19:15.516043 IP 192.168.1.133.55284 > dns.xxx.pl.domain: 64751+ PTR? 155.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (44)
18:19:15.591622 IP dns.xxx.pl.domain > 192.168.1.133.55284: 64751 NXDomain 0/1/0 (115)
18:19:15.953235 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 99, length 64
18:19:15.953812 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 99, length 64
18:19:16.953311 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 100, length 64
18:19:16.955149 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 100, length 64
18:19:17.953353 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 101, length 64
18:19:17.957049 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 101, length 64
18:19:18.953643 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 102, length 64
18:19:18.954942 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 102, length 64
18:19:18.964016 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.1 tell 192.168.1.133, length 46
18:19:18.964654 ARP, Reply 192.168.1.1 is-at 44:1e:a1:3d:e3:36 (oui Unknown), length 28
18:19:19.953499 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 103, length 64
18:19:19.954509 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 103, length 64
18:19:20.521712 IP 192.168.1.133.35953 > xxx.pl.domain: 64751+ PTR? 155.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (44)
18:19:20.524172 IP xxx.pl.domain > 192.168.1.133.35953: 64751 NXDomain 0/1/0 (115)
18:19:20.953602 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 104, length 64
18:19:20.953625 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 104, length 64
18:19:21.953619 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 105, length 64
18:19:21.955911 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 105, length 64
18:19:22.953700 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 106, length 64
18:19:22.953724 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 106, length 64
18:19:23.953721 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 107, length 64
18:19:23.954634 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 107, length 64
18:19:24.953837 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 108, length 64
18:19:24.955166 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 108, length 64
18:19:25.526973 IP 192.168.1.133.55284 > dns.xxx.pl.domain: 64751+ PTR? 155.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (44)
18:19:25.527718 IP dns.xxx.pl.domain > 192.168.1.133.55284: 64751 NXDomain 0/1/0 (115)
18:19:25.953872 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 109, length 64
18:19:25.954173 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 109, length 64
18:19:26.953926 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 110, length 64
18:19:26.954283 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 110, length 64
18:19:27.953975 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 111, length 64
18:19:27.954940 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 111, length 64
18:19:28.954047 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 112, length 64
18:19:28.954219 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 112, length 64
18:19:29.954161 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 113, length 64
18:19:29.956431 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 113, length 64
18:19:30.633106 IP 192.168.1.133.mdns > 224.0.0.251.mdns: 0 PTR (QM)? 155.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (44)
18:19:30.954208 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 114, length 64
18:19:30.954535 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 114, length 64
18:19:31.634965 IP 192.168.1.133.mdns > 224.0.0.251.mdns: 0 PTR (QM)? 155.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (44)
18:19:31.954242 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 115, length 64
18:19:31.956892 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 115, length 64
18:19:32.954308 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 116, length 64
18:19:32.954323 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 116, length 64
18:19:33.637792 IP 192.168.1.133.mdns > 224.0.0.251.mdns: 0 PTR (QM)? 155.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (44)
18:19:33.954386 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 117, length 64
18:19:33.955436 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 117, length 64
18:19:34.954469 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 118, length 64
18:19:34.956300 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 118, length 64
18:19:35.535640 IP 192.168.1.133.49359 > xxx.pl.domain: 25834+ PTR? 109.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (44)
18:19:35.540854 IP xxx.pl.domain > 192.168.1.133.49359: 25834 NXDomain 0/1/0 (115)
18:19:35.954492 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 119, length 64
18:19:35.958736 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 119, length 64
18:19:36.954570 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 120, length 64
18:19:36.957627 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 120, length 64
18:19:37.954587 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 121, length 64
18:19:37.957188 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 121, length 64
18:19:38.954707 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 122, length 64
18:19:38.954731 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 122, length 64
18:19:39.954721 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 123, length 64
18:19:39.958968 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 123, length 64
18:19:40.541158 IP 192.168.1.133.51285 > dns.xxx.pl.domain: 25834+ PTR? 109.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (44)
18:19:40.617464 IP dns.xxx.pl.domain > 192.168.1.133.51285: 25834 NXDomain 0/1/0 (115)
18:19:40.954839 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 124, length 64
18:19:40.955927 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 124, length 64
18:19:41.954885 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 125, length 64
18:19:41.956015 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 125, length 64
18:19:42.954885 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 126, length 64
18:19:42.954908 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 126, length 64
18:19:43.954963 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 127, length 64
18:19:43.957784 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 127, length 64
18:19:44.955045 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 128, length 64
18:19:44.958610 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 128, length 64
18:19:45.546565 IP 192.168.1.133.49359 > xxx.pl.domain: 25834+ PTR? 109.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (44)
18:19:45.547949 IP xxx.pl.domain > 192.168.1.133.49359: 25834 NXDomain 0/1/0 (115)
18:19:45.955110 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 129, length 64
18:19:45.956237 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 129, length 64
18:19:46.955326 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 130, length 64
18:19:46.961571 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 130, length 64
18:19:47.955220 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 131, length 64
18:19:47.955244 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 131, length 64
18:19:48.955309 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 132, length 64
18:19:48.955332 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 132, length 64
18:19:49.955391 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 133, length 64
18:19:49.963315 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 133, length 64
18:19:50.552030 IP 192.168.1.133.51285 > dns.xxx.pl.domain: 25834+ PTR? 109.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (44)
18:19:50.558578 IP dns.xxx.pl.domain > 192.168.1.133.51285: 25834 NXDomain 0/1/0 (115)
18:19:50.955424 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 134, length 64
18:19:50.958131 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 134, length 64
18:19:51.955457 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 135, length 64
18:19:51.956353 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 135, length 64
18:19:52.955532 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 136, length 64
18:19:52.956103 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 136, length 64
18:19:53.955572 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 137, length 64
18:19:53.962819 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 137, length 64
18:19:54.955635 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 138, length 64
18:19:54.965442 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 138, length 64
18:19:55.658235 IP 192.168.1.133.mdns > 224.0.0.251.mdns: 0 PTR (QM)? 109.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (44)
18:19:55.955686 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 139, length 64
18:19:55.956405 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 139, length 64
18:19:56.659989 IP 192.168.1.133.mdns > 224.0.0.251.mdns: 0 PTR (QM)? 109.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (44)
18:19:56.955766 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 140, length 64
18:19:56.959140 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 140, length 64
18:19:57.955818 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 141, length 64
18:19:57.955832 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 141, length 64
18:19:57.966401 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.1 tell 192.168.1.133, length 46
18:19:57.966407 ARP, Reply 192.168.1.1 is-at 44:1e:a1:3d:e3:36 (oui Unknown), length 28
18:19:58.662824 IP 192.168.1.133.mdns > 224.0.0.251.mdns: 0 PTR (QM)? 109.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (44)
18:19:58.955878 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 142, length 64
18:19:58.959587 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 142, length 64
18:19:59.955935 IP 192.168.1.133 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6937, seq 143, length 64
18:19:59.958454 IP 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.133: ICMP echo reply, id 6937, seq 143, length 64
18:20:00.560680 IP 192.168.1.133.34705 > xxx.pl.domain: 22360+ PTR? 219.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (44)
```

In this log we can see that server sends reply to client, and client receive some of them, but ping program dont show any answers. When i change client ip address to one from working addresses, it pings gateway and everything is ok. I have half random addresses which dont work and i dont know how to recognize them and find out why they dont work.

Comment: Its difficult to understand your topology. Can you draw a simple diagram  of your network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my problem. It was old /etc/ethers file without write access and with very old entries.